# is there any limit to the number of engagement split we can use in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

Is there any limit to the number of engagement split we can use in marketing cloud or to the number of links we can track of an email.
I tested with 30 splits and 31 links but just wanted to know if there are any limitations to this features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly no documented limitation. From my fairly extensive experience with the [Interaction Specification](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/interaction-specification/getting-started-spec.html), there shouldn't (in theory) be any technical limitations either. We have created Journeys with ~100 Activities and haven't experienced any issues.

Comment: Ok, I was actually worried about the number of links that the engagement split can track in the email, is there any limit in terms of that

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.